# SimpleSAML\Error\Exception: Could not find the metadata of an IdP with entity ID

Tags: authentication, centos7, saml, simplesamlphp

We have a self-managed file exchange server that gives the following error when you attempt to log in at the web interface:

```
SimpleSAML\Error\Error: UNHANDLEDEXCEPTION

Backtrace:
1 www/_include.php:17 (SimpleSAML_exception_handler)
0 [builtin] (N/A)
Caused by: SimpleSAML\Error\Exception: Could not find the metadata of an IdP with entity ID 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
Backtrace:
8 modules/saml/lib/Auth/Source/SP.php:315 (SimpleSAML\Module\saml\Auth\Source\SP::getIdPMetadata)
7 modules/saml/lib/Auth/Source/SP.php:720 (SimpleSAML\Module\saml\Auth\Source\SP::startSSO)
6 modules/saml/lib/Auth/Source/SP.php:826 (SimpleSAML\Module\saml\Auth\Source\SP::authenticate)
5 lib/SimpleSAML/Auth/Source.php:208 (SimpleSAML\Auth\Source::initLogin)
4 lib/SimpleSAML/Auth/Simple.php:167 (SimpleSAML\Auth\Simple::login)
3 lib/SimpleSAML/Auth/Simple.php:109 (SimpleSAML\Auth\Simple::requireAuth)
2 modules/core/www/as_login.php:33 (require)
1 lib/SimpleSAML/Module.php:260 (SimpleSAML\Module::process)
0 www/module.php:10 (N/A)
```

I reviewed the following article as well as a few others:

["Could not find the metadata of an IdP" with drupal and simplesamlphp_auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007465/could-not-find-the-metadata-of-an-idp-with-drupal-and-simplesamlphp-auth)

I have thoroughly reviewed my config/AuthResources.php and metadata/saml20-idp-remote.php files and confirmed that the entity ID and the metadata values match and tried everything else I have found online. This is a business-critical issue, so any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The metadata had expired. When I went to my web portal at https://my-website/saml, under the federation tab it indicated that the metadata was expired.

I went into Azure and downloaded the "Federation Metadata XML" file and uploaded it to the "XML to SimpleSAMLphp metadata converter" and the problem was resolved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).